# Parse store profileImage error

Tags: android, image, file-upload, parse-platform

I am trying to store a profile image to Parse during the usersignup.
I am getting error when I am trying to store the image file along with the user.
This is the code,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("check", "ckpoint signup 2");
        Parse.initialize(this, "NOA", "NOA");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        //initialize
        mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameRegisterEditText);
        mUserEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailRegisterEditText);
        mUserPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordRegisterEditText);
        mRegisterButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
        mPictureButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pictureImageButton);


        mPictureButton.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);


        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pictureImageButton);



        //Register Button listener
        Log.d("check", "ckpoint 2");
        mRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //Log.d("check", "ckpoint 2");
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Log.d("check", "ckpoint signup click register 100");
                final String username = mUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                final String password = mUserPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                final String email = mUserEmail.getText().toString().trim();



                //Parse picture
                imageView.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
                // Convert it to byte
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
                // Create the ParseFile
                final ParseFile file = new ParseFile("Profile.png", image);
                // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
                file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void done(ParseException e) {
                                              if (e != null) {
                                                  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                                                  builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                                                  builder.setTitle("Sorry");
                                                  builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                      @Override
                                                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                                          dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                                      }
                                                  });
                                                  AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                                  dialog.show();
                                              }
                                              else
                                              {
                                                  Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Sucessfully saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                              }
                                          }
                                      },
                        new ProgressCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(Integer integer) {

                                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                                user.setUsername(username);
                                user.setPassword(password);
                                user.setEmail(email);
                                user.put("ImageProfile",file);

                                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                                        if (e == null) {
                                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Sucessfully signed up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            //take user home
                                            Intent takeUserHome = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
                                            startActivity(takeUserHome);
                                        } else {

                                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                                            builder.setTitle("Sorry");
                                            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                                }
                                            });
                                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                            dialog.show(); }}});}}); }; });}
```

But I am getting error saying that 
Unable to encode an unsaved parse file, i know that there are already questions, but what I want to know is how can i make sure that the file is uploaded first then proceed on to do the next steps? also y can't i just do all this at the same time? is this is how the API is written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the whole user.signUpInBackground code into file.saveInBackground:done from ProgressCallback:done....